# UTF-8 Character encoding issue with DataNucleus JDO application (exposing MySQL database)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jdo, datanucleus

I have a DataNucleus JDO web application that exposes a MySQL database table as a web service. One of the table rows contains text in the Russian.  When the web service returns that row, that text displays as ?'s.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I have confirmed that the data in the MySQL database table is in fact encoded correctly. When I view the data in MySQL Workbench, it displays correctly.
2. I tried writing a small MySQL client in Java that simply connects to the database and prints out the row. At first, I was receiving similar output (all ?'s).  I then tried running the client with a JVM argument, `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, and it worked.
3. I am running the web services in Tomcat. I tried adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to JAVA_OPTS in catalina.bat, and there was no change.
4. I have my JDBC Connection URL specified as a property in my pom.xml file, and it is referenced in the jdoconfig.xml.  I tried appending `?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the connection url, and I keep receiving the following NullPointerException error when I try to reach the web service:

   java.lang.NullPointerException
       org.datanucleus.api.rest.RestServlet.doGet(RestServlet.java:271)
       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

I'm all out of ideas now. I've been careful to make sure that I am viewing any output in a medium that supports UTF-8 encoding. I don't have a lot of experience with DataNucleus and the JDO API, so I'm wondering if I am missing something related to that.

Comment: for your option 4, that is what you have a log for

Comment: To which log are you referring?

Comment: You're using DataNucleus, so let's try that one ;-)

Comment: I've isolated the problem to be with Apache JDO, and not DataNucleus. When I use Jersey to build a RESTful web service within the DataNucleus project, the encoding is handled correctly.

Comment: suggest you report whatever you've found to the Apache JDO project then, with which class of theirs you think is doing something incorrectly, otherwise they won't know about it, and nothing will be done about it.

Comment: did you figure out the issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Nope, I stopped using JDO and created my own web service to resolve the issue.